# Editable Text in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am new in react native and I need some help. I am trying to handle a TextInput where the user can update the text value whatever they want. For example, if the user creates a folder named "Bar" but later on the user decides to change the name for "Bar1". How can I do it???

Here is my code so far: where value={prosp.children} is the text value "Bar". onChangeText={(text) => handleText(text)}, here text is undefined for now but latter it will be my text update "Bar1" or whatever the user writes.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, TextInput} from "react-native";
import styles from "../globalStyles/Styles";

const FolderList = (props) => {
  const handleText = (value, text) => {};

  return (
    <View style={styles.homeRowFolder}>
      <View style={styles.iconAndText}>
        <TextInput
          value={props.children}
          onChangeText={(text) => handleText(text)}
          style={styles.textdisplay}
        ></TextInput>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default FolderList;
```

I want to use react hooks as well.
Thank you so much for the help in advance. Appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

In the event handler function, you are expecting two parameters. `value` and `text`

```
  const handleText = (value, text) => {};
```

But only one is passed from the event handler.

```
onChangeText={(text) => handleText(text)}
```

You need to change handleText so that it takes in only the passed in text and this should work.

```
const handleText = (text) => { 
    console.log(text); // should print the updated text
};
```

You don't need to use hooks to handle this interaction. But if you are doing anything with the data such as saving it in a state you can use an appropriate hook for that.

Comment: Hi @nipuna777 I want to update my current value={props.children} for the new user textInput. Also, replace the data and saving it into the state. How can I do it??

Comment: You should not update the props. The idea is to keep the data flowing from parent components to child components. You can use something like the useContext hook to send the change to the parent component. https://alligator.io/react/usereducer/